# Image is not displaying in the landscape mode

Tags: android

We have Written a program in android for Camera application. When We click the photo in portrait mode every thing working fine Image will display on screen and stored in the camera/dcim folder but when I click the Image in the landscape mode the Image will store in the camera/dcim but it is not display on the screen.

Comment: r u using native camera app? if not try the following code.
Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
       startActivityForResult(camera, PHOTO_REQCOD);

Comment: yes we are using native camera application. wil your code still work? Android_Crazy

Comment: startActivityForResult(camera, PHOTO_REQCOD); how to get PHOTO_REQCOD ?  @Android_Crazy

Comment: PHOTO_REQCOD is just  integer constant used as a requestid in startactivityforresult() mehtod as a second parameter.

Comment: taht we are using by another variable name but it is still not working in potraite mode. thank you for reply